# Check if a column exists in DF - Java Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to check if there is any method to see if a particular column exists in a Dataframe, and check it using Java Spark.
I searched and ended up with suggestions related to Python, but nothing related to Java.

i am extracting this data from Mongo and trying to check certain columns exist or not. There is no schema validation available in the mongo db for this table.

The following is my Schema and i would like to check if they exist with my config of columns.

```
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- acctId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- conId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- dimensions: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- device: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- accountId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- addFreeTitleTime: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- build: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- countryOfResidence: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- createDate: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- number: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- FamilyName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- did: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- deviceToken: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- initialBuildNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- language: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- major: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- minor: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- model: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- modelDesc: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- modelId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- modifyDate: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- preReg: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- retailer: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- serialNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- softwareUpdateDate: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- softwareVersion: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- sourceId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- timeZone: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- location: struct (nullable = true)
```

Your inputs and suggestions would be of great value.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What about the `columns()` function?

Comment: @Dennis Kozevnikoff ---
i tried columns() , but after that find () method is not available

Answer (score 2):

```
sourceDF.printSchema
//  root
//  |-- category: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- tags: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- datetime: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- date: string (nullable = true)

  val cols = sourceDF.columns
//  cols: Array[String] = Array(category, tags, datetime, date)

  val IsFieldCategory = cols.filter(_ == "category")
//  IsFieldCategory: Array[String] = Array(category)
```

or

```
val isFieldTags = sourceDF.columns.contains("tags")
//  isFieldTags: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Hi @mvasyliv - Thanks for sharing the same, but i am looking for solution towards Java. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can achieve this in Java by fetching all the columns of a Dataset and checking if the column you want exists or not. Giving sample example here :

```
Dataset<Object1> dataSet = spark.read().text("dataPath").as(Encoders.bean(Object1.class)); //load data in dataset
String[] columns = dataSet.columns(); // fetch all column names
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(columns).contains("columnNameToCheckFor")); //check if the column name we want to check exist in the array of columns.
```

Here I have used a very naive method to check if the column name exist in the array of columns, you can use any other method to perform this check.

Comment: Hi @Neha Kumari , thanks for sharing, let me try to implement the same. I would also like to know if we can check and if not there then add a null to that column if not exists ?

Comment: Yes sure you can do that. Check “withColumn” option. Let me know if you want me to provide a sample code for that.

Comment: When i am trying to print the column Array, it prints only the ID,Value. 
The MongoDB JSON is quite structure of 152 columns in the JSON Array and they are internally it is like {ID , value { a,{b,c},a1,{b1,c2:{c21,c22}}}

I need to internal column names a1,a2 to be checked. 

If you can share the sample code for adding null for columns not present it will be helpful and give me an Idea.

Comment: can be covered as a different question? Let's maintain the SoC in questions for a sane community. Also if the current answer solves the problem mentioned in current question, should accept it to increase visibility to other people who will face the same issue in future.

Comment: Hi @Neha Kumari - I am looking to pick up the column names in the nested Json from MongoDB.
I have missed to mention that in the question. Let me update it. 
Sorry for the confusion.